# Open a text box when other is selected in dropdown list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table "fundings" in which there is a field "status", for which i have a select field in the form. The options for this select field are `["approved",  "declined", "pending"]`. What i want is when "declined" is selected, a further text box shows to explain the reason for decline. Please help how can this be done.

```
<%= form_for([@parent, @child, @funding], :html => {class: "form-horizontal",role: "form"}) do |form| %>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= form.label :status %>
    </div>

    <% if current_user.admin? %>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.select :status,['Pending', 'Approved', 'Declined'], class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <!-- Disabled for non-admin users -->
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <!-- Submit button here -->
<% end %>
```

Update

```
     <div class="form-group">
  <%= "Status" %>
  <%= form.select :status, ['Pending', 'Approved', 'Declined'], {}, id: "sample-status-select", class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= "Decline Reason" %>
  <%= form.text_area :decline_reason, class: "form-control hidden", id: "decline-reason-textarea" %>
</div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= form.submit "Apply", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <plain>
  $(function() {
    $("#sample-status-select").on("change", function() {
      var select_val = $(this).val();
      console.log(select_val);
      if (select_val === 'Declined') {
        $("#decline-reason-textarea").removeClass("hidden");
      } else {
        $("#decline-reason-textarea").addClass("hidden");
        $("#decline-reason-textarea").val("");
      }
    });
  });
  </plain>
</script>
```

Comment: this requires some javascript.

Comment: @JoshBrody please help me with that.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: _"a further text box opens to explain the reason of decline"_ - what is the name of other text_box field here? You can keep that field always present in the HTML and show/hide based on the value of `status` field using some custom javascript.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU i removed tags `ruby-on-rails-4` and `ruby-on-rails-5` from the question. I don't think your application depends on both.

Comment: have you tried the solution I advised below? the idea is that there is already a text_area field in the html, but it is just hidden initially. then there is a trigger on change of the status that will show/hide the text_area.
if it does not work, kindly inform me so we can try other solutions

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have added a hidden field decline_reason **<%= form.text_area :decline_reason, class: "form-control hidden", id: "decline-reason-textarea" %>**

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro I just tried it. But it is not working

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro Please check the update above. It is not working.

Comment: you can try to reach me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173996/open-a-text-box-when-other-is-selected-in-dropdown-list-in-rails

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU I am able to make it work now, some typo in the javascript. I will give you the code by updating my answer below.

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro it still didn't work for me. I have added the javascript code in application.js and html code in _form.html.erb

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU sorry was out on the weekend, i think it wont work inside application.js because it has the <script> html tag, you should put it in the _form.html.erb file at the bottom for now. and try again. I have made it work by doing that, as shown in my answer (the javascript is coded inside the form file)

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro Please check the update above. It is still not working for me.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU i updated my answer below, kindly check. thanks :)

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro I have edited your answer and posted it. Thankyou so much for all the help. "Declined" had to be in double quotes

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU good job! glad you had it working.

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sample-status-select").on("change", function() {
    var select_val = $(this).val(); // this gets the value of the dropdown menu
    console.log(select_val); // this just displays the selected value in the browser console (if you have the browser console open)

    if (select_val === 'Declined') {
      // if the 'Declined' option is chosen
      // we remove the 'hidden' class from the textarea
      $("#decline-reason-textarea").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      // if any other option is chosen
      // we put back the 'hidden' class to the textarea
      // also, we update the textarea value to BLANK (this part is optional, it depends if you want to keep the value of the textarea)
      $("#decline-reason-textarea").addClass("hidden");
      $("#decline-reason-textarea").val("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  Status
  <select id="sample-status-select">
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
    <option value="Declined">Declined</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br> Decline Reason
  <textarea id="decline-reason-textarea" class="hidden">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Check this snippet I made. It should work for you as well.
This is a basic html form so this works even without ruby on rails.
After you get the gist of this, you should be able to port for it to work with your rails app.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#sample-status-select").on("change", function() {
      var select_val = $(this).val();
      console.log(select_val);
      if (select_val === "Declined") {
        $("#decline-reason-textarea").removeClass("hidden");
      } else {
        $("#decline-reason-textarea").addClass("hidden");
        $("#decline-reason-textarea").val("");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```